# GIT How can I track empty folder with its permission

Tags: git, gitignore

I need to track a folder (I'll name it "root") that contains empty folders.
So I created an empty .gitignore for each empty folder, I added them but now I'd like to track its permissions (`chmod 777 root -R`).
But nothing doesn't change on `git status`

Comment: I can't change something on my production's server, so I need a solution that I can do on `git push` or something like that.

Comment: Don't comment on your own question, edit it instead!

Comment: Anyway, you'll need to do something on the box where you want to manage the permissions. Either existing, or your own script, but you'll need to run something there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git does not track permissions. It only tracks executability. For the matter, no other common version control tool tracks permissions either. So you need something built on top of those tools to track permissions. E.g. [etckeeper](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/).

This works by adding hooks in the repository that:

1. When committing, record the permissions in special file and add it to the commit.
2. When checking out, modify the permissions according to the content of the special file.

You could even put up something simple single-purpose yourself; it's rather simple (that's what holygeek talks about below).

Note, that the hooks run in the work tree. Other repositories that just store the data don't need anything and you can even check out the data elsewhere without the tool. The files will not have the defined permissions there though.

Comment: You can add a bootstrap script that when run it ensures that the folders have the right permissions.

Comment: @Jan Hudec : Will I need to install it on the server (production) where I'll `git pull` ?

Comment: @holygeek : Could you explain me?

Comment: @Math: It has nothing to do with pull and push. Absolutely, totally nothing. It only has to do with the work tree. Where you want a work tree with managed permissions, there you need the tool to manage permissions. That tool can be something existing (like etckeeper) or a script you put up yourself (as suggested by holygeek).

Comment: @Math: Commit a shell script into your repository that will do the chmod on the folders for you.

Comment: Thanks guys. Is there any way to link my script (chmod) to git pull (I heard about `git hook`?)

Comment: @Math: **Not pull**. Haven't I said that it has nothing to do with pull and push already? It's commit and checkout (ok, ok, pull does a checkout at it's end). Yes, look up "hooks" in the user manual.